# C++: make unique_ptr null by reference to unique_ptr object

Tags: c++, object, pointers, unique-ptr

This might be a stupid question, but can I make unique_ptr null by reference to unique_ptr object?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    int& b = *a.get();
    
    // use "b" to make "a" nullptr

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are no stupid questions. There are questions that could benefit from some clarification ;). Why do you think you need to do this? `b` does not "know" about the pointer, it is not possible.

Comment: Fyi, not a reference to a unique_ptr object; it's a reference to the object *pointed to* by a unique_ptr (which is itself an object, but not the one pinned to the shown reference).

Comment: There is no way to use `b` in this manner. What is the real problem that you're trying to solve? No, not the one about making an existing `unique_ptr` null, in this manner, but the one to which you believe this is the solution so that's what you're asking about. Perhaps if you explain what your real question is, a different solution will become obvious.

Comment: Not sure what you actually want to do, but to "make a `unique_ptr` null", you can use `a.release()`. You have to make sure that you eventually delete the released pointer, or you will leak memory.

Comment: OT: You can write just `int& b = *a;` instead of using `*a.get()`.

Comment: This is a textbook X/Y Question. To get any useful answer, i.e. not just 'No', you need to explain _why_ you _think_ you want to do this, i.e. what problem you're actually trying to solve, not just the peculiar way you are currently trying to solve it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to do that. An `int` is just an `int` and a reference to an `int` is just a reference to an `int`. It does not know about pointers that hold its address.